# Is there a way to resize a Kaboom game when the window is resized

Tags: replit, kaboom

Consider the following simple [kaboom](https://kaboomjs.com/) "game":

```js
kaboom();

function makeWallComps(name, x, y, w, h) {
  return [
    name,
    "wall",
    origin("center"),
    rect(w, h),
    pos(x, y),
    outline(),
    area()
  ];
}

let leftWall = add(makeWallComps("left", 5, height() / 2, 10, height()));
let rightWall = add(makeWallComps("right", width() - 5, height() / 2, 10, height()));
let topWall = add(makeWallComps("top", width() / 2, 5, width() - 20, 10));
let bottomWall = add(makeWallComps("bottom", width() / 2, height() - 5, width() - 20, 10));

let obj = add([
  "obj",
  origin("center"),
  rect(20, 20),
  pos(width() / 2, height() / 2),
  outline(),
  area(),
  { dir: rand(-180, 180) }
]);

obj.use(move(obj.dir, 100));

// bounce
obj.collides("wall", function huh(obstacle) {
  if (obstacle.is("left")) {
    console.log("left");
    if (obj.dir < -90) {
      obj.dir = -180 - obj.dir;
    } else if (obj.dir > 90) {
      obj.dir = 180 - obj.dir;
    }
  } else if (obstacle.is("right")) {
    console.log("right");
    if (obj.dir < 0) {
      obj.dir = -180 - obj.dir;
    } else {
      obj.dir = 180 - obj.dir;
    }
  } else if (obstacle.is("top")) {
    obj.dir *= -1;
  } else if (obstacle.is("bottom")) {
    obj.dir *= -1;
  }
  obj.use(move(obj.dir, 100));
});

window.addEventListener(
  'resize',
  () => {
    // I want to resize the game window
    // This does not work: 
    // canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    // canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    
    leftWall.use(pos(5, height() / 2));
    leftWall.use(rect(10, height()));
    rightWall.use(pos(width() - 5, height() / 2));
    rightWall.use(rect(10, height()));
    topWall.use(pos(width() / 2, 5));
    topWall.use(rect(width() - 20, 10));
    bottomWall.use(pos(width() / 2, height() - 5));
    bottomWall.use(rect(width() - 20, 10));
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/kaboom@2000.0.0-beta.24/dist/kaboom.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to be able to resize the canvas and have that reflected by the built in kaboom functions. Unfortunately explicitly setting the canvas dimensions doesn't work, and `KaboomCtx` doesn't appear to have any resize function. Is there any way to resize a kaboom game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I read through some of the Kaboom source code and discovered this this is pretty severely not-modifiable after initialization.

```
const app = appInit({
    // gconf.width is the initial width specified in the call to kaboom()
    width: gconf.width,
    height: gconf.height,
    scale: gconf.scale,
    crisp: gconf.crisp,
    canvas: gconf.canvas,
    root: gconf.root,
    stretch: gconf.stretch,
    touchToMouse: gconf.touchToMouse ?? true,
    audioCtx: audio.ctx,
});

const gfx = gfxInit(app.gl, {
    background: gconf.background ? rgb(gconf.background) : undefined,
    width: gconf.width,
    height: gconf.height,
    scale: gconf.scale,
    texFilter: gconf.texFilter,
    stretch: gconf.stretch,
    letterbox: gconf.letterbox,
});

// This creates functions width() and height() that just returns the values passed to gfxInit()
const {
    width,
    height,
} = gfx;
```

It turns out there is already an [open feature request](https://github.com/replit/kaboom/issues/124) for this. Based on the current state of the code that seems like it will be quite the chore to implement.

Comment: ah glad to know you found the answer yourself, i was busy due to some work from some days

Answer (score 0):

You can resize game using kaboom's inbuilt `scale()` function. It must be run when initializing kaboom, like:

```js
kaboom({
    scale: 4,
});
//This multiplies game size by 4
//your kaboom code here
```

[Here's the official documentation for `scale()` function.](https://kaboomjs.com/#scale)

**NOTE:** After changing kaboom's scale, it may change position of sprites so you may need to re-adjust them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I'm specifically looking for a way to **re**size the game, *after* creation. This is because I want my game to be responsive to the window being resized (or the aspect ratio changing, for example because the user rotates their device).

Comment: @PaulWheeler are you using some replit kaboom template or is it simple html/node.js repl, you're using for development

Comment: As you can see from the runnable snippet in my question, this is just HTML and javascript. However, if I find an answer I will be applying it to use cases hosted on Replit.com with their Kaboom template. I do specifically want to use the kaboom.js library.

Comment: Oh ok, actually repl.it kaboom template looks same, so i was confused. Let me try some thing.

Comment: After reviewing the Kaboom source code I've come to the conclusion that it's impossible for the time being. I hope you didn't waste too much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty fix would be to use `window.innerWidth & innerHeight` on start:

```
kaboom({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
})
```

you probably know the rest but in case someone else reads this:

on window resize , destroy the old kaboom and recreate it again , with some debounce/throttle to avoid so many recreating.

and before destroying save the current state of the game and reapply it on the next build , and show some loading when recreating .